# Xcode not finding classes in my build, but works in a co-worker build (we have same version)

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction

I have a perplexing situation going on with Xcode.

My colleague and I have the same svn revision of our code.

When I open Xcode and try to build the build will succeed. However if click on any class, it will suddenly find errors that it can't find class types for objects I am using.

On my colleagues computer and with his build, Xcode runs it fine and does not encounter errors when he opens a class file.

The errors I get are:
"Use of undeclared identifier"
"Unknown type name"

Can you think of some issue, perhaps in the build settings, that might be causing my compiler issues when I inspect classes?

Comment: check that the .m is included in the build phases > compile sources.

Comment: It is included there yes

Comment: I deleted my source folder and added my co-workers and it works again, so Im not sure what the original problem was, but if this clarifies anything and you might know why it works now I'd love to hear from you! (Id love to know the root cause)

Comment: you could use a tool like DiffMerge, compare folders, and see whats different that your co-workers code works and yours doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your build settings, in the search field, enter "header search path"

you'll see the build settings short list the Header Search Paths section

Double click on the value. Most probably, the search path is not relative.

It may be /Users/userName/Desktop/yourProjectFolder

Change it to
"$(SRCROOT)/yourProjectFolder/" or "$(SRCROOT)/"

If this is not the problem, post some screenshots of the errors.